# Windows XP Mode won't login without changing network settings

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, windows

I have a Windows 7 x64 Enterprise system.  I've installed Windows XP Mode, Windows Virtual PC, and the update.  Everything was running fine for a time, nice integration and all that.  I don't run the XP Mode VM all the time and eventually I launched it and it failed to log in to my domain.  The nasty part is if I switch the network settings from "NAT" to my physical adapter it can contact my domain and log in.  However, if I hibernate and launch again I have to switch the network settings back to be able to log in again.

So no matter what the network setting is on, NAT or Physical, on each launch I must switch it to the other one for it to be able to contact my domain and log in.

I do have VMWare Player and VirtualBox installed on this machine, but neither is running when I attempt to do this.  I've installed all available updates and not sure what else to try.  I recently uninstalled the Windows Virtual PC update, rebooted, reinstalled, rebooted and it has had no affect.

Comment: Are you sure it's talking to your DC?  Try changing your password, and see if you can still log in.  It sounds like maybe your XP machine might have to be re-joined to the domain.

Comment: I'm sure it is talking to the DC because I CAN log in once I've changed the network setting.  Swapping the settings allows me to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to shut down instead of hibernate on Close (which is the default action upon Close) and then change the network settings to see if they stick.

Comment: No dice.  Tried both "shut down" and "turn off" still have to swap network settings on startup.